# sharepoint 2013 installation on sqlserver 2008 r2

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Can we install sharepoint 2013 enterprise on sqlserver 2008 r2 management studio, if not then in whichversion of sqlserver we can install our sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the answers in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx

You'll need the The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or the The 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1